# DateFormat in kotlin give different output in different devices

Tags: android, kotlin, time-format

```
tvSetTime.text = DateFormat.format("hh:mm a", Date(calendar.timeInMillis)).toString()
```

Above code output in 
MI A1 : "12:00 PM"
Moto 6 : "12:00 PM"

but, in Redmi 5 : "12:00 pm"

Is it just MIUI thing?

Comment: Does devices use the same locale?

Comment: add `.toUpperCase()`

Comment: Using [this `DateFormat` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/text/format/DateFormat)? I’d use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) any time…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the Redmi 5 set on the same locale as the MI A1?
You could enforce a locale to get consistent results on devices with different language settings:

```
val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.US)
return dateFormat.format(Date())
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know SimpleDateFormat will work. But why DateFormat gives me different output cuz SimpleDateFormat extends DateFormat. can you explain please?

Comment: I've never seen this DateFormat class before. The original one from Java is abstract and has no method called format with these arguments.

Comment: You need to see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat). Thanks anyway...